# Linux how to replace asterisk using sed

Tags: sed, replace

I have pattern as `*********` in a file and want to replace with `**`. I used `sed -i 's/*********/**/I' filename.txt` But I am getting error as `sed: -e expression #1, char: Invalid preceding regular expression` I tried escaping `*` like `sed -i 's/*********/\*\*/I' filename.txt` but that did not help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ echo "*********" | sed -E 's/\*{9}/\*\*/'
**
```

Without an valid input file we could suggest:

```
$ echo "*********" | sed 's/\*\{9\}/**/'
**
```

Use within sed the `-i` option if you need to store the output in the same file.

Comment: Can you tell what is `**` on the second line?  Also, I want to search for pattern `*********` and not `**`. File has another pattern `**`, which I don't want to touch.

Comment: @uen187 Yes, I can. `**` on the second line is the output from the line before. Mostly a command line starts with `$`.

Comment: @uen187 Could you please give a valid input file.

Comment: @uen187 Try with basic regex: `sed -i 's/\*\{9\}/**/' file`